# Draw multiple lines on the same graph in Matlab? plot() or something else?

Tags: matlab, plot, line

I want to draw several dots, and lines connecting some of the dots. So I programmed like this:

```
prompt = 'Please enter the file name: ';
FileName = input(prompt, 's');
SaturationFile=fopen(FileName);

PoreCount  =fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', 1);
ThroatCount=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', 1);

PI=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', PoreCount);
PX=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f\n', PoreCount);
PY=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f\n', PoreCount);
PS=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', PoreCount);

TI=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', ThroatCount);
TB=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', ThroatCount);
TE=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', ThroatCount);
TA=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f\n', ThroatCount);
TL=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f\n', ThroatCount);
TS=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', ThroatCount);

TB=TB+1;
TE=TE+1;

MaxA=0;
for i=1:ThroatCount
    if TA(i)>MaxA 
        MaxA=TA(i);
    end
end

scale=10;
PX  =PX  *scale;
PY  =PY  *scale;
TA  =TA  *scale;
MaxA=MaxA*scale;

for i=1:ThroatCount
    if TS(i)==0
        c='cyan';
    else
        c='black';
    end
    plot([PX(TB(i)) PX(TE(i))], [PY(TB(i)) PY(TE(i))], 'Color', c, 'LineWidth', TA(i));
end

for i=1:PoreCount
    if PS(i)==0
        c='cyan';
    else
        c='black';
    end
    rectangle('Position', [(PX(i)-0.5*MaxA) (PY(i)-0.5*MaxA) MaxA MaxA], 'FaceColor', c, 'EdgeColor', c, 'Curvature', [1 1]);
end
```

The resulting picture is this:
unbelieveable, sorry, I cannot post pictures, but if you run my program with the sample data, you will easily get my picture.

The Sample Input File:

```
9
10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1.16667
1.16667
1.16667
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.83333
1.83333
1.83333
-0.666667
-0.333333
0
-0.666667
-0.333333
0
-0.666667
-0.333333
0
1
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
0
1
1
3
3
4
4
6
7
1
3
2
4
4
6
5
7
7
8
0.0610206
0.0606029
0.0601841
0.0612494
0.0593242
0.0589063
0.0599607
0.0595583
0.0591209
0.0601974
0.333333
0.333333
0.333333
0.333333
0.333333
0.333333
0.333333
0.333333
0.333333
0.333333
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Question1:
As defined, there should be 10 lines draw between dots, but why there is only 1 line there?

Question2:
Looks like the dots are scaled up, but the line remain that narrow thin line, why?

Thanks! Please help me out, got stuck for a long time.

Comment: If you plot one point at a time in a loop then you won't get the lines joining the points. Maybe try something like `plot([PX(TB) PX(TE)], [PY(TB)) PY(TE)], 'Color', c, 'LineWidth', TA)` *instead* of your loop, depending on your dimensions you might need to change those horizontal concatenations to vertical by adding a `;`: `...[PX(TB); PX(TE)]...`

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax, could you write that small section of the program out? Thanks.

Comment: ... I did. `plot([PX(TB) PX(TE)], [PY(TB)) PY(TE)], 'Color', c, 'LineWidth', TA);`...

Comment: I used this sentence, but it won't draw the plot I want, it will connect with the wrong dots. And also this cannot assign different color to different lines

Comment: Then transpose? e.g. `plot([PX(TB) PX(TE)]'...`

Comment: No! error message: vectors must be the same lengths

Comment: Thanks, anyway! Is there any other command can also draw a line in matlab? See? I can draw multiple dots without any problem.

Comment: well you have to transpose both `x` and `y`. Your question is very unclear, how do we know what points you want to join? Just use `plot`, not in a loop. From [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) *If X and Y are both matrices, then they must have equal size. The plot function plots columns of Y versus columns of X.* so if you have `n` points per line then to plot `10` lines your `X` and `Y` should both be *n*-by-*10* so just rearrange your data appropriately and call `plot` once

Comment: Yes, transpose both works!!! Thanks. But they all share the same color, can  I make them different color?

Comment: That's because of your `c` parameter. Make it a vector too e.g. if you have 3 line and want the first two blue and the last black then `c` must be `[0,0,1;0,0,1;0,0,0]`. If you want each line to be a different color then just leave out the `...'Color',c,...` bit completely

Comment: Thanks, Dan, I believe this one will work eventually! except I didn't figure out how to create array to hold the color yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to put `figure, hold` on before starting to plot (before the ThroatCount loop).